# How do I create a map with string key and array as value (brickhouse hive UDFs)

Tags: hive

I have a table with the following columns

```
transaction_id,
mode,
tag_name,
tag_type
```

There could be multiple tag names for a transaction_id and each tag name could have varying types (in the context of the transaction)

I'm trying to create a new table out of this

```
transaction_id,
mode
tagnametype map<tag_name, tag_type>
tagtypename map<tag_type, array<tag_name>>
```

using a single query

```
create table transaction_tags
select transaction_id, mode, collect(tag_name, tag_type), collect(tag_type, tag_name)
from transactions
group by trans
action_id, mode
```

The first map has no issues as tag_name's for a transaction are unique and it will have all the values. But the second has only one value for each type. Which tells me it is acting like a Java Map where latest overwrites existing. Is there a value to collect all of this in one array against the key?

Something like an inversion. Like for example inversion(map(k,v)) = map(v, [k])

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the following query should work, but is probably not what you want to do.
I'm not sure if the current Hive optimizer can do this query in a single MapReduce Job. (My guess is no.)

```
SELECT transaction_id,
       mode,
       tn.tagnametype,
       tt.tagtypename 
FROM
  ( SELECT transaction_id, mode,
           collect( tag_name, tag_type ) as tagnametype
     FROM trans_table
     GROUP BY transaction_id, mode
  ) tn
JOIN
  ( SELECT transaction_id, mode,
          collect( tag_type, tag_name_array ) as tagtypename
    FROM
      ( SELECT transaction_id, mode,
               collect( tag_name ) as tag_name_array 
         FROM trans_table
         GROUP BY transaction_id, mode
      ) tc
  ) tt
ON ( tn.transaction_id = tt.transaction_id 
  AND tn.mode = tt.mode );
```

Perhaps we should add a 'gather' or 'accumulate' UDF, which creates an array with all values seen for a key.  Please add feature request on the github site ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse/issues )

Comment: Thanks Jerome. I see you have already opened a feature request. Is there a milestone you are targetting for this feature?

Comment: We're shooting for end of month or early next month for next release (0.7) or the next one after that (0.8).  The most recent release has been delayed because of transitional issues.